# How to export blob data from multiple rows in oracle into multiple files on local machine

Tags: java, python, database, oracle

The table in oracle database has :

**FileName     FileType    Data**

***abc.xlx      excel     blob***

***def.pdf      pdf       blob***

This database is hosted on a central server. I want to extract this data from multiple rows into multiple files. If I try doing it through SQL developer, I can do it for one row at a time. Is there any way to can be done for multiple rows?

UTL_FILE stores the files on the database server. But I want to store them on my machine.

Can it be done by a stored procedure? Or should a Java utility be written?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/export-blob

Comment: Code inside a database cannot have access to your **local** filesystem, so it cannot be a stored procedure. When you fetch something from the database to the application side, it has no matter where that *something* came from: a database table, a web service responce, was generated by the application or any other way. So you may fetch BLOB with any programming language and save it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/05/exporting-multiple-blobs-with-oracle-sql-developer/) explains in detail how it is done with SQL Developer. In summary it is possible. Open the cart (view menu) and drag your table to it. Select loader format, add filters and select separate files.